# action is executing completely and two times the html is rendered but the content of the page is not loading without refreshing the page in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

This is my controller action

```
def grant_spend_money
  set_organization_users_permission(:can_spend_money, true)
end

def revoke_spend_money
  set_organization_users_permission(:can_spend_money, false)
end

def set_organization_users_permission(permission_name, permission_value)
  @organization = current_user.organization
  organization_user = @organization.users.where(id: params[:user_id]).first
  organization_user.update_attribute(permission_name, permission_value)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :users_permission  }
  end
end
```

This is user_permission.js.erb file

```
$("#users_list").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'organization_user', collection: @organization.users.order(:id), as: :user) %>");
```

Comment: try removing the respond_to block

Comment: Not it don't work